How to scale header/footer with document in openxlsx2
I am using openxlsx2 to create an excel document and scale the content to one page for printing. However the font size of the footer is not scaled as well. In Excel there is an option called Scale with document to achieve this, but I haven't found an parameter for this in openxslx2. Is there a way to "insert" that property into wb?
Here is an example showing the unscaled footer:
library(openxlsx2)

wb <- wb_workbook() %>%
  wb_add_worksheet(footer = c(NA, "Footer", NA)) %>%
  wb_page_setup(fit_to_width = 1) %>%
  wb_add_data(x = mtcars)

wb$open()


Not possible at the moment. scaleWithDoc="0" is hard coded, but probably just because nobody had a use case and/or nobody understood what it does. Feel free to open an issue on our github and some example file or at least screenshots to show what is expected to happen, would be great.
